# I was working in the wrong repo. They are almost the same but not associated data. How do i diff/merge?

Tags: version-control, mercurial

Can you diff with the reverted copy?

I was doing work in the wrong repo.  They are almost the same, but have no actual relation.

I just did a pull and an update, can i then copy my changed files into the Right head and then run a diff on it or something similar and then properly merge the 2 together?

I feel an alternate option would be do something like
copy the code over and commit it, then revert back, and merge with the commit to diff what has all changed..

I have changing something like 1500 lines over 9 files, so i dont want to rewrite a bunch of code segments.

How should i handle this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It really depends on how similar the "almost the same, but have no actual relation" repositories are.

If they *extremely* similar (as in files have the same names and text is almost identical), you might get by with exporting a patch at the source repo and then importing the same patch into the target repo.

In the source repo:

```
hg export -r tip > path\to\oops.patch
```

and in the target repo:

```
hg import path\to\oops.patch --no-commit
```

I used `--no-commit` since I assume you will need to do some cleanup first to make sure that everything looks ok.

Alternatively, you could just compare the two directories using kdiff or BeyondCompare3 and bring over the differences that you want from the source repo to the target repo and commit it that way. This would probably be my approach.

(*I am intentionally ignoring the question about why you have two repositories that are that similar but don't have a shared history. For all I know, it might be the right thing to do.*)

Comment: All those options look like they would be good.  Im going to look into kdiff and BeyondCompare3 to see if those work.  If they dont i will attempt the patch approach. All 3 seem like they would work.  Ill give an update when i get a success, give you the thumbs up and tell you which approach worked best for me.

Comment: I used kdiff.  It worked, i Liked it, because it will do a diff on 2 directories OR files.... and then will output it.